# List all uncommited changes in HP vertica

Tags: commit, vertica

Is there a way to list all uncommitted changes HP vertica ?
Something like a command which lists all commands whose effects were not committed.

Comment: I'm quite certain this is not possible. You can only see uncommitted changes within a transaction as [Jim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31320675/679449) explains.

Comment: I am curios what does commited/uncommitted in Vertica means to you @Kermit

Comment: @Up_One User runs an `UPDATE` statement, and walks away from his terminal before running `COMMIT`

Comment: @Kermit - changes for me means "make data consistent" in normal RDBMS this happens at "commit" time in Vertica is a bit different as you may know.

Comment: @Up_One However we don't know if OP is loading into WOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the EPOCH column for the table. If it is NULL then the data is uncommitted.

Simple example:

```
dbadmin=> create table jim (a int);
CREATE TABLE
dbadmin=> insert into jim values (1);
 OUTPUT
--------
      1
(1 row)

dbadmin=> select *, epoch from jim;
 a | epoch
---+-------
 1 |
(1 row)

dbadmin=> commit;
COMMIT
dbadmin=> select *, epoch from jim;
 a | epoch
---+--------
 1 | 424446
(1 row)
```

Comment: It should be noted that this will only work within the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

By uncommitted changes you mean data that is stored in **WOS** ?

- the **WOS** data is stored in if so :

  **select * from projection_storage where wos_used_bytes > 0;**
- all the data that is stored to WOS and is not passed to ROS stays in memory, so if you get cought with data in WOS and you cluster goes down you will loose that data.

**Here is a small demo of you can loose WOS stored data :**

```
--create a table
    (dbadmin@:5433) [dbadmin] > create table test(name varchar(10));
    CREATE TABLE
--insert some data using default method (no direct hint)
    (dbadmin@:5433) [dbadmin] > insert into test values('Adrian');
     OUTPUT
    --------
          1
    (1 row)
-- commit your data (makes no difference if data is in WOS)
 (dbadmin@:5433) [dbadmin] > commit;

   -- look for WOS stored data
    (dbadmin@:5433) [dbadmin] *> select * from projection_storage where wos_used_bytes > 0;
    -[ RECORD 1 ]-----------+------------------
    node_name               | v_d_node0001
    projection_id           | 45035996273828324
    projection_name         | test_super
    projection_schema       | public
    projection_column_count | 2
    row_count               | 1
    used_bytes              | 16384
    wos_row_count           | 1
    wos_used_bytes          | 16384
    ros_row_count           | 0
    ros_used_bytes          | 0
    ros_count               | 0
    anchor_table_name       | test
    anchor_table_schema     | public
    anchor_table_id         | 45035996273828322

    -- kill vertica process
(dbadmin@:5433) [dbadmin] *>\! kill -9 21582 21596 21580 5883 5866

    -- try a query 
(dbadmin@:5433) [dbadmin] *> select * from projection_storage where wos_used_bytes > 0;
    server closed the connection unexpectedly
            This probably means the server terminated abnormally
            before or while processing the request.
    The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
    (@:) [] ?>
    (@:) [] ?>
    (@:) [] ?> \q

  -- start vertica 
    [dbadmin@DCG023 ~]$ vsql
    Password:
    Welcome to vsql, the Vertica Analytic Database interactive terminal.

    Type:  \h or \? for help with vsql commands
           \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
           \q to quit

 -- see if data was commited
    (dbadmin@:5433) [dbadmin] > select * from test;
     name
    ------
    (0 rows)

 -- see WOS stored data  
    (dbadmin@:5433) [dbadmin] *> select * from projection_storage where wos_used_bytes > 0;
    (No rows)
```

To move your data from **WOS** to **ROS** you can use the `/*+ DIRECT */` hint with your statement or run the `do_tm_tack('moveout')` manually after the statement(this operation is done automatic in the background at preset intervals).

If data stays in **WOS** more then the `MoveOutInterval` parameter value that you need to see why this is happening.

Also look at you **locks** table for any object locks.